# Running regressions on subsamples: Include the variable on which the subsample is based in the regressions?

Tags: sample, truncation

Income is one of my independent variables in a sample of 2000 households. I'd like split the sample along household income lines (poor, vulnerable and non-poor). Is there a reason not to include income as independent variable?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If your income variable from the outset is categorical with values poor,  vulnerable and non-poor, then after splitting the sample in three subsamples there is no variation left in that variable, so including it makes no sense. (and if you try, the design matrix will be "singular" (rank-deficcent), so your software will protest.  On the other hand, if at the outset your income variable is numerical, then after splitting, there is still variation left, so now including it makes sense.  Again, if there is much measurement error in it, after splitting that might well dominate the variation, and in such case it should not be included.

If you decide to include it, then the interpretation of the variable and its coefficiewnt will be different from in the full sample model:  Now it differentiates by income within the "poor" group, say, so it tells you if income diffferences within the poor really matters.

Comment: I forgot to mention that income is continuous, sorry. Thank you for the definite answer. I was just worried that there might be any truncation problems (which, I guess, would only be there if income was the dependent).